# Raven matrix/grid puzzle

Tags: pattern

[image]

Which from A to F fills in the blank?

I can make 2 observations:

> Whatever happens on line 1 happens on column 2; same goes for line 2, column 1 and line 3, column 3. This suggests that the same rule applies both horiz/vert.

and

> If the point above is true then order of symbols is not important in a line/column.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, [proper attribution](/help/referencing) is required. If you have permission to repost this, please edit to include (at minimum) where it came from, then vote to reopen. Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally [deleted](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1348).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> E

Because...

> The last element in each row is made by coloring the points black if only the points of the first 2 elements is all white, and after that, rotating it 90 degrees counterclockwise.

Answer (score 0):

The last element of each row and column is made by

> colouring all points that are coloured in one or both of the preceding elements, and then turning the resulting image upside down.

So this would produce

> An element with up, right and left coloured

Unfortunately that's not one of the options provided...

Comment: that was the same pattern I identified, but there are not enough cases to corroborate that that pattern is meaningful.  I could say that the pattern is, for example: that you add all the colored dots from column 1 to column 2, resulting in column 3.  If there are any overlapping dots, in addition to filling column 1 and column 2 dots, you also rotate the square one rotation.  The answer is therefore, A